# Can I perform hyerarchical clustering using scikit with a similarity measure?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, cluster-analysis, distance

I am currently working with a set of people and a compatibility score which I have represented in an excel file.

I want to group the people according to the compatibility score and then use hierarchical clustering.

As far as I know, I should just take the score and divide 1 by it to obtain a distance. However, I have some scores which are 0.

I have tought on using the exponential of the score to be able to avoid the division by zero.

This leaves me with some questions. Is my idea adequate? should I use the euclidean distance in the clustering?

Comment: If your compatibility score has a maximum value (e.g. a percentage with a maximum value of 100), why not just use `max_value - compatibility_score` as your distance.